# ng-bootstrap datepicker not working

Tags: angular, datepicker, ng-bootstrap

I am trying to use ng-bootstrap date picker in my angular2 project but getting following error.

```
There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "ngbDatepicker"
```

Here is my code

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
     <div class="input-group">
         <input class="form-control" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"
         name="dp" [(ngModel)]="model" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker">
          <button class="input-group-addon" (click)="d.toggle()" type="button">
    <img src="img/calendar-icon.svg" style="width: 1.2rem; height: 1rem; cursor: pointer;"/>
  </button>
</div>
```

Any help would be appriciated

Comment: Post all the relevant code, showing you have installed ng-bootstrap correctly in your app (your app module)

Comment: read careful instaltion guide. Remember include  NgbModule.forRoot() OR NgbModule in the provider of the module that include your component -if it's the main module or not-

Comment: Thanks Eliseo  i was missing .forRoot()

Answer (score 13):

I had same problem. In my case it was missing NgbModule import in module where directive was in use. So, double check that you import NgbModule.forRoot() in mail module and NgbModule in every module tak use datapicker.

Comment: This should be a comment instead an answer

Answer (score 5):

In order to open the datepicker on `focus` event, you need to add `(focus)="d.open()"` like below:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="date" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker" (focus)="d.open()" name="date_start" class="form-control"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Check the order of imports in your `@NgModule`

You have to put `FormsModule` before `NgbModule`, and do not forget `NgbModule.forRoot()` in your root module

Answer (score 3):

The solution to this issue is very simple. In your project directory, locate the file named **app.module.ts** which is the *AppModule (root module)*.

In that file, under **@NgModule**, there will be an **imports** array. Add 
**FormsModule** and **NgbModule.forRoot()** in it just like given below.

**app.module.ts:**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';


import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NgbModal, NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    NgbModule.forRoot()
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: forRoot is deprecated: 3.0.0. Importing with `.forRoot()` is no longer necessary, you can simply import the module. Will be removed in 4.0.0. ie; you have to mention only `NgbModule` in `imports`

Answer (score 0):

Add property `autoClose="inside"` and paste code in `index.html`

```
$("body").not("input[ngbdatepicker]").click(function (e) {
   if ($(e.target).not("input[ngbdatepicker]").length > 0 && 
       $(e.target).closest("ngb-datepicker").length == 0) {
       $("ngb-datepicker").remove();
   }
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. To make it easy for others to read your questions and answers, please use code formatting.